# Facebook login: persisting across app launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm logging in users with the following method, which works fine. However, each time the app relaunches, I need to run this method again to regain access.

The Facebook documentation seems to be very limited, and all the advice I can find *(including on Stack Overflow)* is related to the old **Facebook SDK**.

From what I can understand, a **FBSDKAccessToken** should be being cached when the user is first logged in. However, when I check `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` on subsequent launches, nothing is returned.

Any advice very welcome.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Process error
     } else if (result.isCancelled) {
         // Handle cancellations
     } else {
         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
              // success           
         }
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, searched for hours then came here 5 minutes too soon. The problem was that I needed to add the following in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ALSO want to add this in the following method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL facebookCheck = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                           openURL:url
                                                 sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                        annotation:annotation];

    if (!facebookCheck){
        ...
    }

    return true;

}
```

You probably wont need it now, but it doesn't hurt. :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had that one. I actually followed the setup instructions, but for some reason missed the didFinishLaunching one.

Comment: Also what i liked more, then having the return value of facebooks methods directly affecting my AppDelegate method. I just called them and saved the result in a BOOL variable. That way you can check if the facebook methods worked without a problem, eventually handle any errors or try to do it again.
Check my answer, I'll have it updated. :)